# Submit a link without refreshing and without ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a link that when you click it gets an image and saves it to the server

I want to make it so when you click a link in a list, it runs the script but it doesn't actually go to the page.
I tried e.preventdefualt but then that doesn't submit the link

```
<li><a href="view.php?id=867hjhgjghj">867599386384729100r</a></li>
```

That would run the php necessary to save the image on the server, I know how I'd do this with ajax but I saw a site doing it without.

```
$('#lia').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: What site is doing this without AJAX? Is it using flash? A java applet (*shudders*)? Using a JSON post request?

Given the edit you just made, just having a click event bound to the id you put there (wwhich is not present in your HTML snippet) you're just telling it to do nothing when it's clicked and that's all.

Comment: why don't you want to use AJAX?

Comment: @charlietfl I ask myself the same thing, but I figure why not humor him and give myself a challenge :)

Comment: https://github.com/nykac/5napChat the run view without that I think

Comment: 1) Their photo booth code is minified and impossible to read. 2) All the upload code I can find is using AJAX

Comment: I'm talking about their view.php which outputs the image, their photo booth is for taking pictures. They are downloading the image to the server, not the uploading part.

Comment: That's PHP code...which is run server side...I'm back to square one with being positively confused as to what on earth you are trying to do.

Comment: The server executes PHP files are executed when they are called by an HTTP request. The only ways to make an HTTP request from JavaScript are loading a link (synchronous) or sending an XMLHttpRequest (AJAX)... There's no other way to get the PHP code to run.

Comment: As far as I can see they are using ajax. Look at line 95 in index.php, there is an interval set which make an ajax request every 5th second.

Answer (score 3):

You could accomplish this with AJAX by doing:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.get(this.href);
});
```

I know the title says without refreshing or ajax, but I think that was a mistake.

Comment: I sure hope it was a mistake ;)

Comment: This works but I don't see them just this, I'm still curious where the code for how 5napchat is submitting the data for view.php

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. If you take a look at the network tab you should see the request for the `view.php` file.

Comment: yes i'm aware of that but where is the line that makes it preventdefualt or $.get or ajax 
As far as I know link 95 in index doesn't effect that

Comment: I see what you're talking about now. You don't need to `.preventDefault()` if there's no action you're trying to avoid (such as the browser following a link). There's no one clicking on a link so there's no reason for `.preventDefault()`.